# Is it possible to store a GADT inside a State monad transformer?

Tags: haskell

Say that I have got a GADT like this:

```
data Term a where
  Lit    :: a -> Term a
  Succ   :: Term Int -> Term Int
  IsZero :: Term Int -> Term Bool
  If     :: Term Bool -> Term a -> Term a -> Term a
```

Is it possible to store `Succ (Lit 2)` and `IsZero (Succ (Lit 2))` inside the State monad transformer, as a value of the internal state?

The issue here being those two are of different types, and I don't know how the `s` of `StateT s m a` should be typed.

Edit: `ATerm` solved the initial question of how to store different `GADT` in the state, the issue now is since the type is lost it seemed impossible to compare the old and new state.

Edit: Final answer.

After going back and forth with @luqui, here's the full code snippet that answers this question.

Feel free to fork this [repl](https://repl.it/@coodoo1/OfficialDarkgreyProgramminglanguages) and have a try.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Data.Typeable

data Term a where
  Lit    :: a -> Term a
  Succ   :: Term Int -> Term Int
  IsZero :: Term Int -> Term Bool
  If     :: Term Bool -> Term a -> Term a -> Term a

deriving instance (Eq a) => Eq (Term a)

data ATerm where
  ATerm :: (Typeable a, Eq a) => Term a -> ATerm

instance Eq ATerm where
    ATerm t == ATerm u
        | Just t' <- cast t = t' == u
        | otherwise = False

main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weaken GADTs type constraints to deal with unpredictable data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53904818/weaken-gadts-type-constraints-to-deal-with-unpredictable-data)

Comment: You shouldn't need the `Typeable a` constraint on the `Lit` constructor.

Comment: Alternatively, you can shove the `Eq` constraint in there too, and remove both constraints from the `ATerm` constructor. [Example](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/40ff82031132e642faaedac39fed6fb6)

Comment: Thanks @dfeuer for pointing out the extra constraint, code updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use an existential

```
data ATerm where
   ATerm :: Term a -> ATerm
```

which is a monotype that stores "a `Term` of any type".

However you should be aware that you will *lose* the type information, which I have a hunch will not cause a problem in your case.  If you do need to recover it, you will need to add some `Typeable` constraints or some other trick—hard to say without more context on what you are doing.

**EDIT**

To get the type information back, you will need to include it in `ATerm`

```
data ATerm where
    ATerm :: (Typeable a, Eq a) => Term a -> ATerm
```

Sadly, this change might cause the `Typeable` constraint to infect a fair amount of your code.  That's just how it goes.  We also include `Eq a`, since if we are comparing `ATerms` and do find that their types are the same, we will need to compare on that type.

Then to compare two `ATerm`s, you first need to compare their types, then their values.  This can be done with the [`Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html) library.

```
instance Eq ATerm where
    ATerm t == ATerm u
        | Just t' <- cast t = t' == u
        | otherwise = False
```

Luckily, your `Term` GADT doesn't hide any types.  If you had a case like, for example

```
data Term a where
    ...
    Apply :: Func a b -> Term a -> Term b
```

you would need to add `Typeable` also to any hidden variables (variables that don't appear in the result type)

```
    Apply :: (Typeable a) => Func a b -> Term a -> Term b
```

Roughly, if you want to compare types, you need to have a `Typeable` constraint on them somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I revised it a bit and then it worked like a charm!

Comment: You may also like [`Some Term`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parameterized-utils-1.0.1/docs/Data-Parameterized-Some.html), not least for the collection of handy utilities you get for reuse.

Comment: @luqui ended up you are correct in that the type will be lost once put inside ATerm, is there any way to retrieve it back since I need to compare the old state to the new state?

Comment: @DonKlein, I have expanded the answer

Comment: @luqui I tried your updated example but got some errors as shown [in this screencap](https://imgur.com/1wb7AbJ), mind having a look?

Comment: @DonKlein, made a tiny mistake.  Should be `t' == u` instead of `t == u`

Comment: @luqui, actually that's the first thing I tried but no dice, you could try it here (press "Run" to see the error message on the right): https://repl.it/@coodoo1/OfficialDarkgreyProgramminglanguages

Comment: @DonKlein you forgot an `Eq` instance for your `Term`, and I forgot that we therefore need to close over an `Eq` dictionary in `ATerm` (assuming the former is compositional, which it almost surely will be).  https://repl.it/@luqui/OfficialDarkgreyProgramminglanguages-3

Comment: @luqui Thanks, it worked like a charm this time and I've updated the question with full code snippet 